# HashTable overWrite

Tags: c, list, hashtable

I'm tryng to make an hash table in c, but I have a little issue when i try to insert elements in the table.

When I try to insert Pairs like this, everything works perfectly.

```
{
    char c1[] = "www.google.com";
    char c2[] =  "8.8.8.8";
    char c3[] = "www.yahoo.com";
    char c4[] =  "67.195.160.76";
    char c5[] = "www.olx.ro";
    char c6[] = "192.228.79.201";
    put(tabel, c1, c2 , sizeof(TPair), f);
    put(tabel, c3, c4, sizeof(TPair), f);
    put(tabel, c5, c6, sizeof(TPair), f);

    AfiTD(tabel);
}
```

But when I try to read something from file, the current insertion overwrite the previous insertion;

TPair structure contains two char* fields: key and value.
Cast to (void*) is required because I have to use generic lists in Hash Table.

http://gyazo.com/648e3aa0b06fe662f18b337993271eed
http://gyazo.com/9a1f1613ed70572ce3132c8cc1213ce5

Comment: Your code needs better variable names. It's impossible to understand what "cod", "aux", "aux2" "aL", "rez" etc is suppose to do. For your sake as much as everyone else, make them more understandable ;)

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your code too much; are you copying the contents of the key/value into the internal data structure? Otherwise you might store a pointer to data that changes, screwing with your lookups.